# Como faz para capturar dois inteiros com espaço entre eles em python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

to querendo capturar dois inteiros, exemplo:

> 2 4

exatamente assim em python, mas ele por int(input()) normal n vai, eu tenho feito assim, mas deve ter outra forma:

```
var = input()
lista = []
lista = var.split(' ')
n,q = lista
n = int(n)
q = int(q)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Com espaço, teria que ser algo assim... Mas se for por virgula, pode ser assim:

```
[a,b]=list(input("Insira dois numeros separados por virgulas: "))
print "Numero 1:", a
print "Numero 2:", b
```

No terminal:

```
Insira dois numeros separados por virgulas: 12,28
Numero 1: 12
Numero 2: 28
```

Comment: Descobri q assim tambem vai, quase a mesma coisa, mas fica mais compacto ^^
a,b = list(map(int,input().split(' ')))

Comment: essa resposta sem o "split" está simplesmente errada.  Por que está com upvotes e aceita??

Comment: @PythonFocus: por favor, para melhorar a qualidade do site, evite marcar como "aceita" uma resposta que não funciona - mesmo que ela te inspire a aachar a resposta certa. Lembre-se de que outras pessoas estarão consultando essa resposta para referência - ao ver o "aceite" é assumido que está correto.

Answer (score 3):

A função `input` sempre retornará uma *string*, independente do conteúdo lido, então, se é necessário obter dois inteiros a partir de uma *string*, separados por uma vírgula, a lógica será basicamente a mesma que quando separados por um espaço em branco: só muda o caractere separador.

Por exemplo:

```
entrada = input('Entre com dois números separados por vírgula:')
x, y = (int(numero) for numero in entrada.split(','))
print(x, y)
```

Desta forma, inclusive, é possível entrar com entradas na forma "2, 3", com o espaço entre a vírgula e o número, pois, quando convertido para inteiro, o espaço será ignorado.